# How to reference a variable-named field in an ADODB recordset

Tags: vba

I'm currently working on a project which looks like this:

```
set rs15 = new adodb.recordset
dim course1 as string
course1=label1

rs15.open " select * from  CourseYear where Surname like' " & text12 & " ' ", con1, 3, 3

rs15!(course1)=text1.text
rs15.update


msgbox "success"
```

`course1` is a string contains the `label1` which corresponds to the field name on my database. I was trying to call that label in `rs15!(course1)`, but it says type-declaration character does not match the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a variable named field by using the `Fields` property directly. Instead of the `recordset!fieldname` notation use `recordset.Fields(fieldname)`.

In your case this would be: `rs15.Fields(course1)=text1.Text`

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/the-fields-collection) for more information